# TYPO3 RTE Editor not loading

Tags: typo3, rte, typo3-4.5

Today in one of our older sites we found an issue with the RTE Editor. For any of our users the editor does not load. It is stuck on loading as you can see in the image below.
[image]

Now I realize that the version we are using for TYPO3 is extremely outdated, the version is 4.5 support has been gone for ages and I wouldn't dare to just update this site.

We haven't updated or changed anything in the configuration so this wouldn't be the case. I've also tried to remove all caches from the site, create a new user and give them all rights and trying several different computers. None of this has helped fix the issue.

Wondering if anyone has a idea on where to search or how to solve this.

Comment: Try to install this extension : https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/rtehtmlarea/
May this will solve your prolem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using Chrome 73 as browser? This version breaks the rtehtmlarea integration. You need to backport the [patch which is provided for TYPO3 8.7](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/rtehtmlarea/issues/26#issuecomment-477308231).

File: typo3/sysext/rtehtmlarea/htmlarea/htmlarea.js
Line : 2224

search for:

```
src: Ext.isGecko ? 'javascript:void(0);' : (Ext.isWebKit ? 'javascript: '' + HTMLArea.htmlEncode(this.config.documentType + this.config.blankDocument) + ''' : HTMLArea.editorUrl + 'popups/blank.html')
```

change to:

```
src: Ext.isGecko ? 'javascript:void(0);' : (Ext.isWebKit ? (Ext.isChrome ? 'about:blank;' : 'javascript: '' + HTMLArea.htmlEncode(this.config.documentType + this.config.blankDocument) + ''') : HTMLArea.editorUrl + 'popups/blank.html')
```

Comment: Currently using chrome version: 73.0.3683.86. Seems like things are indeed working on another browser. I'll try this solution asap

Comment: After extensive testing this was the solution, thank you!

Comment: If you don't want to patch, use the Firefox Browser

Comment: On newer Chrome versions, change to: `src: Ext.isGecko ? 'javascript:void(0);' : (Ext.isWebKit || Ext.isChrome ? '' : HTMLArea.editorUrl + 'popups/blank.html')`

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a javascript error which stops execution of further javascript.
on loading the data is adapted (from TYPO3 format to HTML) and the editor is build by modifying the DOM. As browsers change in behaviour and javascript engine the old javascript might run into errors with current browsers.

You could try to use another browser.

Otherwise you could disable the RTE in the user settings, although it means you have to edit text as HTML source.

Comment: I do have a javascript error; using Edge did work however disabling the RTE in user settings seems like an odd solution, thanks for thinking with me though!

Comment: using very old software requires update stops in multiple ways. in case of TYPO3 that are: PHP, that might require stops in update of operating system. You noticed that you can no longer use all current browsers. As ignoring updates is a big security risk (updates are not only about new features) you make your system vulnerable. You can save work with avoiding updates. but there will be a time where that will end. either you get attacked or the risk of attack is so big you want to update. but then the [technical depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) more than you can manage.

Comment: I fully understand that and an rebuild version of the site is on it's way with the newest version of TYPO3. It's just that we cannot ignore the old build whilst making the new one