# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null at Iframe.initializeIframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, typo3, editor, typeerror

after upgrade Chrome browser to v. 91.0.4472.106, console show this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null
at Iframe.initializeIframe (Iframe.js?bust=f74493421b3bb4c9f2ea18198ca25746b5ef8a20:202)

this is content of Iframe.js:

```
/*
 * This file is part of the TYPO3 CMS project.
 *
 * It is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of the GNU General Public License, either version 2
 * of the License, or any later version.
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please read the
 * LICENSE.txt file that was distributed with this source code.
 *
 * The TYPO3 project - inspiring people to share!
 */

/**
 * Module: TYPO3/CMS/Rtehtmlarea/HTMLArea/Editor/Iframe
 * The editor iframe
 */
define(['TYPO3/CMS/Rtehtmlarea/HTMLArea/UserAgent/UserAgent',
    'TYPO3/CMS/Rtehtmlarea/HTMLArea/DOM/Walker',
    'TYPO3/CMS/Rtehtmlarea/HTMLArea/Util/TYPO3',
    'TYPO3/CMS/Rtehtmlarea/HTMLArea/Util/Util',
    'TYPO3/CMS/Rtehtmlarea/HTMLArea/DOM/DOM',
    'TYPO3/CMS/Rtehtmlarea/HTMLArea/Event/Event',
    'TYPO3/CMS/Rtehtmlarea/HTMLArea/Event/KeyMap'],
    function (UserAgent, Walker, Typo3, Util, Dom, Event, KeyMap) {

    /**
     * Editor iframe constructor
     *
     * @param {Object} config
     * @constructor
     * @exports TYPO3/CMS/Rtehtmlarea/HTMLArea/Editor/Iframe
     */
    var Iframe = function (config) {
        Util.apply(this, config);
    };

    Iframe.prototype = {

        /**
         * Render the iframe (called by framework rendering)
         *
         * @param object container: the container into which to insert the iframe (that is the framework)
         * @return void
         */
        render: function (container) {
            this.config = this.getEditor().config;
            this.createIframe(container);
            if (!this.config.showStatusBar) {
                Dom.addClass(this.getEl(), 'noStatusBar');
            }
            this.initStyleChangeEventListener();
            if (UserAgent.isOpera) {
                var self = this;
                Event.one(this.getEl(), 'load', function (event) { self.initializeIframe(); return true; })
            } else {
                this.initializeIframe();
            }
        },

        /**
         * Get the element to which the iframe is rendered
         */
        getEl: function () {
            return this.el;
        },

        /**
         * The editor iframe may become hidden with style.display = "none" on some parent div
         * This breaks the editor in Firefox: the designMode attribute needs to be reset after the style.display of the container div is reset to "block"
         * In all browsers, it breaks the evaluation of the framework dimensions
         */
        initStyleChangeEventListener: function () {
            if (this.isNested) {
                if (typeof MutationObserver === 'function') {
                    var self = this;
                    this.mutationObserver = new MutationObserver( function (mutations) { self.onNestedShowMutation(mutations); });
                    var options = {
                        attributes: true,
                        attributeFilter: ['class', 'style']
                    };
                    for (var i = this.nestedParentElements.sorted.length; --i >= 0;) {
                        var nestedElement = document.getElementById(this.nestedParentElements.sorted[i]);
                        this.mutationObserver.observe(nestedElement, options);
                        this.mutationObserver.observe(nestedElement.parentNode, options);
                    }
                } else {
                    this.initMutationEventsListeners();
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * When Mutation Observer is not available, listen to DOMAttrModified events
         */
        initMutationEventsListeners: function () {
            var self = this;
            var options = {
                delay: 50
            };
            for (var i = this.nestedParentElements.sorted.length; --i >= 0;) {
                var nestedElement = document.getElementById(this.nestedParentElements.sorted[i]);
                Event.on(
                    nestedElement,
                    'DOMAttrModified',
                    function (event) { return self.onNestedShow(event); },
                    options
                );
                Event.on(
                    nestedElement.parentNode,
                    'DOMAttrModified',
                    function (event) { return self.onNestedShow(event); },
                    options
                );
            }
        },

        /**
         * editorId should be set in config
         */
        editorId: null,

        /**
         * Get a reference to the editor
         */
        getEditor: function () {
            return RTEarea[this.editorId].editor;
        },

        /**
         * Get a reference to the toolbar
         */
        getToolbar: function () {
            return this.framework.toolbar;
        },

        /**
         * Get a reference to the statusBar
         */
        getStatusBar: function () {
            return this.framework.statusBar;
        },

        /**
         * Get a reference to a button
         */
        getButton: function (buttonId) {
            return this.getToolbar().getButton(buttonId);
        },

        /**
         * Flag set to true when the iframe becomes usable for editing
         */
        ready: false,

        /**
         * Create the iframe element at rendering time
         *
         * @param object container: the container into which to insert the iframe (that is the framework)
         * @return void
         */
        createIframe: function (container) {
            if (this.autoEl && this.autoEl.tag) {
                this.el = document.createElement(this.autoEl.tag);
                if (this.autoEl.id) {
                    this.el.setAttribute('id', this.autoEl.id);
                }
                if (this.autoEl.cls) {
                    this.el.setAttribute('class', this.autoEl.cls);
                }
                if (this.autoEl.src) {
                    this.el.setAttribute('src', this.autoEl.src);
                }
                this.el = container.appendChild(this.el);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Get the content window of the iframe
         */
        getIframeWindow: function () {
            return this.el.contentWindow ? this.el.contentWindow : this.el.contentDocument;
        },

        /**
         * Proceed to build the iframe document head and ensure style sheets are available after the iframe document becomes available
         */
        initializeIframe: function () {
            var self = this;
            var iframe = this.getEl();
            // All browsers
            if (!iframe || (!iframe.contentWindow && !iframe.contentDocument)) {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    self.initializeIframe();
                }, 50);
            // All except WebKit
            } else if (iframe.contentWindow && !UserAgent.isWebKit && (!iframe.contentWindow.document || !iframe.contentWindow.document.documentElement)) {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    self.initializeIframe();
                }, 50);
            // WebKit
            } else if (UserAgent.isWebKit && (!iframe.contentDocument.documentElement || !iframe.contentDocument.body)) {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    self.initializeIframe();
                }, 50);
            } else {
                this.document = iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow.document : iframe.contentDocument;
                this.getEditor().document = this.document;
                this.createHead();
                // Style the document body
                Dom.addClass(this.document.body, 'htmlarea-content-body');
                // Start listening to things happening in the iframe
                // For some unknown reason, this is too early for Opera
                if (!UserAgent.isOpera) {
                    this.startListening();
                }
                // Hide the iframe
                this.hide();
                // Set iframe ready
                this.ready = true;
                /**
                 * @event HTMLAreaEventIframeReady
                 * Fires when the iframe style sheets become accessible
                 */
                Event.trigger(this, 'HTMLAreaEventIframeReady');
            }
        },

        /**
         * Show the iframe
         */
        show: function () {
            this.getEl().style.display = '';
            Event.trigger(this, 'HTMLAreaEventIframeShow');
        },

        /**
         * Hide the iframe
         */
        hide: function () {
            this.getEl().style.display = 'none';
        },

        /**
         * Build the iframe document head
         */
        createHead: function () {
            var head = this.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            if (!head) {
                head = this.document.createElement('head');
                this.document.documentElement.appendChild(head);
            }
            if (this.config.baseURL) {
                var base = this.document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0];
                if (!base) {
                    base = this.document.createElement('base');
                    base.href = this.config.baseURL;
                    head.appendChild(base);
                }
                this.getEditor().appendToLog('HTMLArea.Iframe', 'createHead', 'Iframe baseURL set to: ' + base.href, 'info');
            }
            var link0 = this.document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0];
            if (!link0) {
                link0 = this.document.createElement('link');
                link0.rel = 'stylesheet';
                link0.type = 'text/css';
                link0.href = this.config.editedContentStyle;
                head.appendChild(link0);
                this.getEditor().appendToLog('HTMLArea.Iframe', 'createHead', 'Skin CSS set to: ' + link0.href, 'info');
            }
            var pageStyle;
            for (var i = 0, n = this.config.pageStyle.length; i < n; i++) {
                pageStyle = this.config.pageStyle[i];
                var link = this.document.createElement('link');
                link.rel = 'stylesheet';
                link.type = 'text/css';
                link.href = pageStyle;
                head.appendChild(link);
                this.getEditor().appendToLog('HTMLArea.Iframe', 'createHead', 'Content CSS set to: ' + link.href, 'info');
            }
        },

        /**
         * Focus on the iframe
         */
        focus: function () {
            try {
                if (UserAgent.isWebKit) {
                    this.getEl().focus();
                }
                this.getEl().contentWindow.focus();
            } catch(e) { }
        },

        /**
         * Flag indicating whether the framework is inside a tab or inline element that may be hidden
         * Should be set in config
         */
        isNested: false,

        /**
         * All nested tabs and inline levels in the sorting order they were applied
         * Should be set in config
         */
        nestedParentElements: {},

        /**
         * Set designMode
         *
         * @param   boolean     on: if true set designMode to on, otherwise set to off
         *
         * @rturn   void
         */
        setDesignMode: function (on) {
            if (on) {
                if (!UserAgent.isIE) {
                    if (UserAgent.isGecko) {
                            // In Firefox, we can't set designMode when we are in a hidden TYPO3 tab or inline element
                        if (!this.isNested || Typo3.allElementsAreDisplayed(this.nestedParentElements.sorted)) {
                            this.document.designMode = 'on';
                            this.setOptions();
                        }
                    } else {
                        this.document.designMode = 'on';
                        this.setOptions();
                    }
                }
                if (UserAgent.isIE || UserAgent.isWebKit) {
                    this.document.body.contentEditable = true;
                }
            } else {
                if (!UserAgent.isIE) {
                    this.document.designMode = 'off';
                }
                if (UserAgent.isIE || UserAgent.isWebKit) {
                    this.document.body.contentEditable = false;
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * Set editing mode options (if we can... raises exception in Firefox 3)
         *
         * @return  void
         */
        setOptions: function () {
            if (!UserAgent.isIE) {
                try {
                    if (this.document.queryCommandEnabled('insertBrOnReturn')) {
                        this.document.execCommand('insertBrOnReturn', false, this.config.disableEnterParagraphs);
                    }
                    if (this.document.queryCommandEnabled('styleWithCSS')) {
                        this.document.execCommand('styleWithCSS', false, this.config.useCSS);
                    } else if (UserAgent.isGecko && this.document.queryCommandEnabled('useCSS')) {
                        this.document.execCommand('useCSS', false, !this.config.useCSS);
                    }
                    if (UserAgent.isGecko) {
                        if (this.document.queryCommandEnabled('enableObjectResizing')) {
                            this.document.execCommand('enableObjectResizing', false, !this.config.disableObjectResizing);
                        }
                        if (this.document.queryCommandEnabled('enableInlineTableEditing')) {
                            this.document.execCommand('enableInlineTableEditing', false, (this.config.buttons.table && this.config.buttons.table.enableHandles) ? true : false);
                        }
                    }
                } catch(e) {}
            }
        },

        /**
         * Mutations handler invoked when an hidden TYPO3 hidden nested tab or inline element is shown
         */
        onNestedShowMutation: function (mutations) {
            for (var i = mutations.length; --i >= 0;) {
                var targetId = mutations[i].target.id;
                if (this.nestedParentElements.sorted.indexOf(targetId) !== -1 || this.nestedParentElements.sorted.indexOf(targetId.replace('_div', '_fields')) !== -1) {
                    this.onNestedShowAction();
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * Handler invoked when an hidden TYPO3 hidden nested tab or inline element is shown
         */
        onNestedShow: function (event) {
            Event.stopEvent(event);
            var target = event.target;
            var delay = event.data.delay;
            var self = this;
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                var styleEvent = true;
                // In older versions of Gecko attrName is not set and referring to it causes a non-catchable crash
                if ((UserAgent.isGecko && navigator.productSub > 2007112700) || UserAgent.isOpera || UserAgent.isIE) {
                    styleEvent = (event.originalEvent.attrName === 'style') || (event.originalEvent.attrName === 'className') || (event.originalEvent.attrName === 'class');
                }
                if (styleEvent && (self.nestedParentElements.sorted.indexOf(target.id) != -1 || self.nestedParentElements.sorted.indexOf(target.id.replace('_div', '_fields')) != -1)) {
                    self.onNestedShowAction();
                }
            }, delay);
            return false;
        },

        /**
         * Take action when nested tab or inline element is shown
         */
        onNestedShowAction: function () {
            // Check if all container nested elements are displayed
            if (Typo3.allElementsAreDisplayed(this.nestedParentElements.sorted)) {
                if (this.getEditor().getMode() === 'wysiwyg') {
                    if (UserAgent.isGecko) {
                        this.setDesignMode(true);
                    }
                    Event.trigger(this, 'HTMLAreaEventIframeShow');
                } else {
                    Event.trigger(this.framework.getTextAreaContainer(), 'HTMLAreaEventTextAreaContainerShow');
                }
                this.getToolbar().update();
            }
        },

        /**
         * Instance of DOM walker
         */
        htmlRenderer: null,

        /**
         * Getter for the instance of DOM walker
         */
        getHtmlRenderer: function () {
            if (!this.htmlRenderer) {
                this.htmlRenderer = new Walker({
                    keepComments: !this.config.htmlRemoveComments,
                    removeTags: this.config.htmlRemoveTags,
                    removeTagsAndContents: this.config.htmlRemoveTagsAndContents,
                    baseUrl: this.config.baseURL
                });
            }
            return this.htmlRenderer;
        },

        /**
         * Get the HTML content of the iframe
         */
        getHTML: function () {
            return this.getHtmlRenderer().render(this.document.body, false);
        },

        /**
         * Start listening to things happening in the iframe
         */
        startListening: function () {
            var self = this;
            // Create keyMap so that plugins may bind key handlers
            this.keyMap = new KeyMap(this.document.documentElement, (UserAgent.isIE || UserAgent.isWebKit) ? 'keydown' : 'keypress');
            // Special keys map
            this.keyMap.addBinding(
                {
                    key: [Event.DOWN, Event.UP, Event.LEFT, Event.RIGHT],
                    alt: false,
                    handler: function (event) { return self.onArrow(event); }
                }
            );
            this.keyMap.addBinding(
                {
                    key: Event.TAB,
                    ctrl: false,
                    alt: false,
                    handler: function (event) { return self.onTab(event); }
                }
            );
            this.keyMap.addBinding(
                {
                    key: Event.SPACE,
                    ctrl: true,
                    shift: false,
                    alt: false,
                    handler: function (event) { return self.onCtrlSpace(event); }
                }
            );
            if (UserAgent.isGecko || UserAgent.isIE || UserAgent.isWebKit) {
                this.keyMap.addBinding(
                {
                    key: [Event.BACKSPACE, Event.DELETE],
                    alt: false,
                    handler: function (event) { return self.onBackSpace(event); }
                });
            }
            if (!UserAgent.isIE && !this.config.disableEnterParagraphs) {
                this.keyMap.addBinding(
                {
                    key: Event.ENTER,
                    shift: false,
                    handler: function (event) { return self.onEnter(event); }
                });
            }
            if (UserAgent.isWebKit) {
                this.keyMap.addBinding(
                {
                    key: Event.ENTER,
                    alt: false,
                    handler: function (event) { return self.onWebKitEnter(event); }
                });
            }
            // Hot key map (on keydown for all browsers)
            var hotKeys = [];
            for (var key in this.config.hotKeyList) {
                if (key.length === 1) {
                    hotKeys.push(key);
                }
            }
            // Make hot key map available, even if empty, so that plugins may add bindings
            this.hotKeyMap = new KeyMap(this.document.documentElement, 'keydown');
            if (hotKeys.length > 0) {
                this.hotKeyMap.addBinding({
                    key: hotKeys,
                    ctrl: true,
                    shift: false,
                    alt: false,
                    handler: function (event) { return self.onHotKey(event); }
                });
            }
            Event.on(
                this.document.documentElement,
                (UserAgent.isIE || UserAgent.isWebKit) ? 'keydown' : 'keypress',
                function (event) { return self.onAnyKey(event); }
            );
            Event.on(
                this.document.documentElement,
                'mouseup',
                function (event) { return self.onMouse(event); }
            );
            Event.on(
                this.document.documentElement,
                'click',
                function (event) { return self.onMouse(event); }
            );
            if (UserAgent.isGecko) {
                Event.on(
                    this.document.documentElement,
                    'paste',
                    function (event) { return self.onPaste(event); }
                );
            }
            Event.on(
                this.document.documentElement,
                'drop',
                function (event) { return self.onDrop(event); }
            );
            if (UserAgent.isWebKit) {
                Event.on(
                    this.document.body,
                    'dragend',
                    function (event) { return self.onDrop(event); }
                );
            }
        },

        /**
         * Handler for other key events
         */
        onAnyKey: function (event) {
            if (this.inhibitKeyboardInput(event)) {
                return false;
            }
            /**
             * @event HTMLAreaEventWordCountChange
             * Fires when the word count may have changed
             */
            Event.trigger(this, 'HTMLAreaEventWordCountChange', [100]);
            if (!event.altKey && !(event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey)) {
                var key = Event.getKey(event);
                // Detect URL in non-IE browsers
                if (!UserAgent.isIE && (key !== Event.ENTER || (event.shiftKey && !UserAgent.isWebKit))) {
                    this.getEditor().getSelection().detectURL(event);
                }
                // Handle option+SPACE for Mac users
                if (UserAgent.isMac && key === Event.NON_BREAKING_SPACE) {
                    return this.onOptionSpace(key, event);
                }
            }
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * On any key input event, check if input is currently inhibited
         */
        inhibitKeyboardInput: function (event) {
            // Inhibit key events while server-based cleaning is being processed
            if (this.getEditor().inhibitKeyboardInput) {
                Event.stopEvent(event);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },

        /**
         * Handler for mouse events
         */
        onMouse: function (event) {
            // In WebKit, select the image when it is clicked
            if (UserAgent.isWebKit && /^(img)$/i.test(event.target.nodeName) && event.type === 'click') {
                this.getEditor().getSelection().selectNode(event.target);
            }
            this.getToolbar().updateLater(100);
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Handler for paste operations in Gecko
         */
        onPaste: function (event) {
            // Make src and href urls absolute
            if (UserAgent.isGecko) {
                var self = this;
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    Dom.makeUrlsAbsolute(self.getEditor().document.body, self.config.baseURL, self.getHtmlRenderer());
                }, 50);
            }
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Handler for drag and drop operations
         */
        onDrop: function (event) {
            var self = this;
            // Clean up span elements added by WebKit
            if (UserAgent.isWebKit) {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    self.getEditor().getDomNode().cleanAppleStyleSpans(self.getEditor().document.body);
                }, 50);
            }
            // Make src url absolute in Firefox
            if (UserAgent.isGecko) {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    Dom.makeUrlsAbsolute(event.target, self.config.baseURL, self.getHtmlRenderer());
                }, 50);
            }
            this.getToolbar().updateLater(100);
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Handler for UP, DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT arrow keys
         */
        onArrow: function (event) {
            this.getToolbar().updateLater(100);
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Handler for TAB and SHIFT-TAB keys
         *
         * If available, BlockElements plugin will handle the TAB key
         */
        onTab: function (event) {
            if (this.inhibitKeyboardInput(event)) {
                return false;
            }
            var keyName = (event.shiftKey ? 'SHIFT-' : '') + 'TAB';
            if (this.config.hotKeyList[keyName] && this.config.hotKeyList[keyName].cmd) {
                var button = this.getButton(this.config.hotKeyList[keyName].cmd);
                if (button) {
                    Event.stopEvent(event);
                    /**
                     * @event HTMLAreaEventHotkey
                     * Fires when the button hotkey is pressed
                     */
                    Event.trigger(button, 'HTMLAreaEventHotkey', [keyName, event]);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Handler for BACKSPACE and DELETE keys
         */
        onBackSpace: function (event) {
            if (this.inhibitKeyboardInput(event)) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((!UserAgent.isIE && !event.shiftKey) || UserAgent.isIE) {
                if (this.getEditor().getSelection().handleBackSpace()) {
                    Event.stopEvent(event);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // Update the toolbar state after some time
            this.getToolbar().updateLater(200);
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Handler for ENTER key in non-IE browsers
         */
        onEnter: function (event) {
            if (this.inhibitKeyboardInput(event)) {
                return false;
            }
            this.getEditor().getSelection().detectURL(event);
            if (this.getEditor().getSelection().checkInsertParagraph()) {
                Event.stopEvent(event);
                // Update the toolbar state after some time
                this.getToolbar().updateLater(200);
                return false;
            }
            // Update the toolbar state after some time
            this.getToolbar().updateLater(200);
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Handler for ENTER key in WebKit browsers
         */
        onWebKitEnter: function (event) {
            if (this.inhibitKeyboardInput(event)) {
                return false;
            }
            if (event.shiftKey || this.config.disableEnterParagraphs) {
                var editor = this.getEditor();
                editor.getSelection().detectURL(event);
                if (UserAgent.isSafari) {
                    var brNode = editor.document.createElement('br');
                    editor.getSelection().insertNode(brNode);
                    brNode.parentNode.normalize();
                    // Selection issue when an URL was detected
                    if (editor._unlinkOnUndo) {
                        brNode = brNode.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(brNode, brNode.parentNode.nextSibling);
                    }
                    if (!brNode.nextSibling || !/\S+/i.test(brNode.nextSibling.textContent)) {
                        var secondBrNode = editor.document.createElement('br');
                        secondBrNode = brNode.parentNode.appendChild(secondBrNode);
                    }
                    editor.getSelection().selectNode(brNode, false);
                    Event.stopEvent(event);
                    // Update the toolbar state after some time
                    this.getToolbar().updateLater(200);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            // Update the toolbar state after some time
            this.getToolbar().updateLater(200);
            return true;
        },

        /**
         * Handler for CTRL-SPACE keys
         */
        onCtrlSpace: function (event) {
            if (this.inhibitKeyboardInput(event)) {
                return false;
            }
            this.getEditor().getSelection().insertHtml('&nbsp;');
            Event.stopEvent(event);
            return false;
        },

        /**
         * Handler for OPTION-SPACE keys on Mac
         */
        onOptionSpace: function (key, event) {
            if (this.inhibitKeyboardInput(event)) {
                return false;
            }
            this.getEditor().getSelection().insertHtml('&nbsp;');
            Event.stopEvent(event);
            return false;
        },

        /**
         * Handler for configured hotkeys
         */
        onHotKey: function (event) {
            var key = Event.getKey(event);
            if (this.inhibitKeyboardInput(event)) {
                return false;
            }
            var hotKey = String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase();
            /**
             * @event HTMLAreaEventHotkey
             * Fires when the button hotkey is pressed
             */
            Event.trigger(this.getButton(this.config.hotKeyList[hotKey].cmd), 'HTMLAreaEventHotkey', [hotKey, event]);
            return false;
        },

        /**
         * Cleanup (called by framework)
         */
        onBeforeDestroy: function () {
            // Remove listeners on nested elements
            if (this.isNested) {
                if (this.mutationObserver) {
                    this.mutationObserver.disconnect();
                } else {
                    for (var i = this.nestedParentElements.sorted.length; --i >= 0;) {
                        var nestedElement = document.getElementById(this.nestedParentElements.sorted[i]);
                        Event.off(nestedElement);
                        Event.off(nestedElement.parentNode);
                    }
                }
            }
            Event.off(this);
            Event.off(this.getEl());
            Event.off(this.document.body);
            Event.off(this.document.documentElement);
            // Cleaning references to DOM in order to avoid IE memory leaks
            this.document = null;
            this.el = null;
        }
    };

    return Iframe;

});
```

error on line 202 by **documentElement || !iframe.contentDocument.body)) {**:

```
} else if (UserAgent.isWebKit && (!iframe.contentDocument.documentElement || !iframe.contentDocument.body)) {
```

How i can fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found the bugfix. In old versions, the iframe source was initialized with *about:blank* in the rtehtmlarea extension, this is the root cause for the problem you are facing. There was an official bugfix 2 years ago - link to Github: https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/rtehtmlarea/commit/a20e23445ca760ba94ed06dca05266b6e22a25fb

You can backport the fix or update the extension, then it is working as expected in the new Chrome version.

Comment: Its fix my problem. You are angel, thx you so much :-)

Comment: Can i modify UserAgent for Edge too ? Etc: . UserAgent.isWebKit || UserAgent.isChrome || UserAgent.isEdge ?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're using a TYPO3 version prior to v8.7 with rtehtmlarea which is outdated and unsupported since quite a while. With TYPO3 v8.7 ckeditor was introduced.

Maybe this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511397/typo3-rte-editor-not-loading) helps you a little bit. Otherwise just use Firefox.

But you're strongly advised to upgrade your TYPO3 installation to the latest version v10.4.