# Rich text editor (rtehtmlarea) in TYPO3 7.6 is not showing content

Tags: typo3, rich-text-editor, typo3-7.6.x

The rich text editor in TYPO3 7.6, called `rtehtmlarea`, is not displaying the content that is saved there and is instead showing this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Here's an image of what it looks like...

[image]

This issue is effecting all recent versions of Chrome/Safari/Edge/Opera, only Firefox is showing the content.

This is a legacy website and the client doesn't have money to upgrade at the moment. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various fixes (you can see them here  https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/rtehtmlarea/commits/master) that fix issues related to Chrome / IE.

As TYPO3 v7 is out of support (even the Extended LTS Support), the way I solved it was to patch the files

Comment: This is helpful info. Didn't know about doing that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem as well, and I think the solution is: use Firefox.

Another idea would be to install older versions of other browsers.

Comment: I don't think that it's a wise idea to install old versions of browsers. That pretty much goes hand in hand with major security risks.

Comment: Yes, that's true. But running a website on TYPO3 V7 is also not optimal. Of course it should only be used for that single task.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked multiple times here on Stackoverflow, e.g. here:
[TYPO3 RTE Editor not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511397/typo3-rte-editor-not-loading)

The only working browser for such old TYPO3 installations is currently Firefox, as already mentioned.

Comment: Thank you for looking that up, BUT that question does not apply here. It's a muuuch older version of TYPO3 than I am using in addition to being a different error. This is an issue unique to that one.